# Express route responding with index.html for every requested file

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

All I want to do is render index.html when this route `/:uuid` is hit. This is my code:

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '../dist'));
app.get('/:uuid', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../dist/index.html'));
})
```

Here is the [full source](http://pastebin.com/yT7YPeSb). The `app.get()` for that route is on line 50. The problem I'm having is that the server responds with the contents of index.html for every requested file. In other words:

[image]

Sorry if I'm overlooking something really obvious. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Please include the actual code in your question - don't link to external source.

Comment: Sorry about that I added the questionable code. @brandonscript

Answer (score 1):

Problem is that if you have route like`/:uuid` everything after `/` gets treated as variable. Solution is to move this `app.get()` down in file so other routes will be evaluated before falling on `app.get(/:uuid ....`